# Framework for Web Services in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services

I need to implement a Web Service in PHP, but I've never written one in it (I nowadays use ASP.net which handles all that SOAP/WSDL/Disco stuff for me).

Are there any libraries/Frameworks for that? Should be as lightweight as possible as they wire into an existing system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP comes with a SOAP client built in:

http://us.php.net/soap

and there's always the ZF version:

[Zend Framework: Zend_Soap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.html)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [Zend Framework](http://zendframework.com/). It's an fully featured framework and it is basically just a bunch of loosely coupled components. You don't have to use anything you don't want to.

You can view the components [here](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/). Notice there is [Zend_Soap](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.soap.html) and others.

Answer (score 3):

Try [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) it's lightweight and very easy to use.